# How to fetch the phone number from other apps in case of default dialer application?

Tags: android

I'm developing a dialer application that can be set as the default phone handler by the user.

In that case, if the user clicks on any phone number from a 3rd party app (say whatsapp), my application is being launched. But, how can I get the phone number that was clicked on by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to my problem. Below is the code.

```
String action = getIntent().getAction();
if ("android.intent.action.DIAL".equals(action) || "android.intent.action.VIEW".equals(action)) {
    Uri data = intent.getData();
    if (data != null) {
        if ("tel".equals(data.getScheme())) {
            this.etDialerNumber.setText(data.getSchemeSpecificPart());
        }
    }
}
```